# Incorrect HTTP Status code

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests, http-status-code-404, broken-links

I get a 404 error while checking the link using requests for the page below while the page opens fine in the browser. Can someone please help me understand what's happening?. I get the same error using [this](http://404checker.com/404-checker) service as well.

```
url = "http://www.dell.com/en-us/learn/assets/corporate~case-studies~en/documents~2014-chitale-dairy-10012962-networking-blades-support.pdf

response = requests.get(url)
print response.status_code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that [Hypertext Transfer Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) is working fine! The pdf file that you trying access is no longer exist or never existed.

[image]